# Is GDPR really needed if my android app doesn't collect any personal data?

Tags: gdpr

I have developed some Android applications, and they don't store any personal data, but they do some calculation about some input, for example the annual salary provided by user and return to him a result to screen without saving any information.
Should this application need any GDPR popup or page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

Given that the app does not transmit any data out of the user's device that can be used to identify the user, GDPR is not relevant whatsoever.

Comment: The description seems to indicate that the app is used for personal use only. But if the app would be used for non-personal use, the GDPR does apply to the person using it. It it true that it would not apply to the app developer, but for the user to use it lawfully non-personal, the app must be GDPR-compliant, for example data export must be possible.

Comment: To be clear, the previous comment only applies if personal data is processed.

Answer (score -1):

Even if your application processes personal data, but keeps it on the device, you do not need to worry about the GDPR. However the user who uses the application, processes that personal data, so (s)he must comply to the GDPR. But I assume the application is only meant to process data from the owner itself. In that case the GDPR does not apply, see [Art. 2(2)(c) GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-2-gdpr/)

> 2. This Regulation does not apply to the processing of personal data:
>
>    (c)    by a natural person in the course of a purely personal or household activity;

If your application transmits data to a website, to perform calculations. The GDPR would apply to you, as the information transmitted includes at least the ip-address and you process that data. In that case having a privacy policy is probably sufficient in your case.

Comment: -1 for spreading the myth that IP address is necessarily personal data. It [may or may not be](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28998/right-of-access-by-the-data-subject-if-the-ip-address-is-the-only-personal-dat/29026#29026). Also, no single bit of GDPR is relevant if user data does not leave his/her device, no matter how it is processed and who wrote the apps.

Comment: @Greendrake GDPR covers the processing of data not merely its transfer; if the data controller (who uses the phone) processes personal data outside of Art 2(2)(c) then the Regulation does apply.