# Is geocoding an IP address but not storing it considered processing under GDPR?

Tags: privacy, gdpr, consent

As a data controller who intends to be GDPR compliant, if someone visits my website a request is made to my server with their IP address.

If I geocode the IP address to get the visitor's country and city and then render something on my website based on this, is that considered data processing?
Note that in this case I wouldn't be storing the ip address, country or city. Once the request is complete these would all be lost.

Comment: Yet another victim of the myth that IP addresses are necessarily personal data. They [may or may not be](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28998/right-of-access-by-the-data-subject-if-the-ip-address-is-the-only-personal-dat/29026#29026).

Comment: @Greendrake You're right, but I guess the question is. If I geocode an IP address to a location ie. City, Country. Is that considered personal data? Obviously I can't identify the person based on the IP address alone. I can't really identify them from the location, but maybe I could? It seems a bit of a blurred line to me.