# Does uploading a project to GitHub make a person joint data controller according to gdpr?

Tags: gdpr

Does uploading an open source GitHub repository intended for commercial purpose make the person who uploaded the code joint data controller?
What is meant is that if code is uploaded to GitHub I have asked GitHub to host it. Now for security of GitHub's website they may collect some information including i.p. addresses. Does this make GitHub a data processor for me under the GDPR? I am not referring to GitHub pages.

Comment: Joint with whom?  Github?  The person downloading and using the code?  Think about it this way, the GDPR is not designed to trip you up - think about what data you *control*, you are a Data Controller for that data, and then think about what data you *process*, you are a Data Processor for that data.  In your scenario, what data do *you* control or process?

Comment: Is the repository public or private? There's a good argument that GH is acting as a data processor on your behalf, as discussed [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/40813). While the linked Q&A is about GitHub Pages, this generalizes to private repositories as well.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the uploader does not decide what categories of information GitHub will collect, nor for what purposes, nor what privacy notice will be provided, nor what consent shall be asked for from Data Subjects. Nor does the uploader have the power to delete particular data records, nor to view date except insofar as it is made available to the general public. I don't see how the uploader in any way fits the GDPR role of Controller. Please correct me if I am mistaken about the role of the uploader to GitHub.

Comment: I was actually cnsidering it over I mean I felt allowing github to host is a big instruction to collect data.

Comment: Similarly fr youtube also then right , when someone allows ads on their video they are not bringing in controllership then(I am nota lawyer.).

Comment: @ask Probably. I don't know what info if any YouTube provides toi content uploaders.